# Do Scala type lambdas cost of a reflective call?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm working with a lot of code with type lambdas at the moment and noticed that IntelliJ is warning me that it's an "Advanced language feature: reflective call".

Sample code:

```
implicit def monoidApplicative[M](M: Monoid[M]) =
  new Applicative[({ type f[x] = Const[M, x] })#f] {
    def unit[A](a: => A): M = M.zero
    override def apply[A,B](m1: M)(m2: M): M = M.op(m1, m2)
  }
```

Note: I figure that this could be a bug the IntelliJ Scala plugin as it would make sense that type lambdas are resolved at compile time.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if you say you have a lot of type lambdas in your code I recommend checking out https://github.com/non/kind-projector

Comment: Perhaps I should. Any idea if the IJ's Scala plugin has support for it?

Comment: I didn't use it myself yet but according to this: http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/07/31/inline-refactoring-for-type-aliases-and-kind-projector-support/ it should be supported from quite some time.

Comment: Seems [it does have support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2015/07/31/inline-refactoring-for-type-aliases-and-kind-projector-support/)!

Comment: @Łukasz, now using the kind-projector and all my IntelliJ (false) warnings about reflective calls have gone away :). Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IDEA just gets confused because of the `{ }` block. None of this code even exists at runtime.

Here is a small example. A generic identity method for types with one type argument:

```
def id[F[_], A](value: F[A]) = value
```

It is not possible to call this method with a type that takes two type arguments:

```
class Test[A, B]
id(new Test[Int, Int])

<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Test[Int,Int]
 required: F[A]
              id(new Test[Int, Int])
```

But we can use a type lambda to define a function id2 that is implemented in terms of id:

```
def id2[F[_, _], A, B](value: F[A, B]) =
  id[({ type f[x] = F[A, x] })#f, B](value)

id2(new Test[Int, Int])
res3: Test[Int,Int] = Test@1a53ac0c
```

Quite convoluted, but it works. Now let's look at the bytecode.

```
scala> :javap -c id2

...

  public <F, A, B> F id2(F);
Code:
   0: getstatic     #19                 // Field .MODULE$:L;
   3: aload_1
   4: invokevirtual #22                 // Method .id:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   7: areturn

...
```

As you can see, there is nothing left of all the type trickery. No reflection, nothing. Just `java.lang.Object`.